# How do you say "to work with?"

Tags: single-word-request

I'm not exactly talking about *arbeiten mit*, but rather "work with" in a context as in the following sentence:

> Please work with me to set things right.

I don't feel like "arbeiten mit" would work in this case. Am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe e.g. "Kannst du mitarbeiten?" or "Könntest du mit mir arbeiten?" or "Bitte arbeite mit mir um die Sache in Ordnung zu bringen".

Comment: _Lass uns gemeinsam …_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example you mean, that someone should help or support you to fix something (e.g. a situation/problem), correct?

Depending on the situation you could say:

> "Bitte hilf mir [to set things right]"

or

> "Bitte unterstütze mich [to set things right]"

or translated a bit more freely:

> "Lass uns daran arbeiten, [to set things right]"

In the last example you could use

> "arbeiten"

without talking about something realted to labour.
I didn't translate "to set things right", because you could translate this in different ways, depending on the context. E.g.

> "Bitte hilf mir, das wieder gerade zu biegen"

or

> "Bitte hilf mir, das wieder in Ordnung zu bringen"

or

> "Bitte hilf mir, das klar zu stellen"

You could insert a "dabei" as well:

> "Lass uns daran arbeiten / Bitte unterstütze mich / Bitte hilf mir
>   dabei, das wieder ..."

Comment: "Bitte hilf mir, das wieder gerade zu biegen" ist IMHO die beste Übersetzung.

Answer (score 4):

"Please work with me to set things right."

"Bitte *arbeite mit mir zusammen*, um die Sache klarzustellen."

Comment: Die direkte Übersetzung finde ich unpassend. "Work with me" heißt in dem Kontext eher "hilf mir". "set things right" ist auch nicht "eine Sache klarstellen", sondern etwas wieder gut machen oder in Ordnung bringen.